# Can my singleton be improved?

Tags: ios, ios5, singleton

I am somewhat new to iOS 5 singletons and am using a singleton as documented here:

[iOS 5 Singletons](http://iosdeveloperforums.com/f9/singletons-ios5-40.html)

Something like this:

MyManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MyManager : NSObject

//Data for section 1
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * section1a;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger section1b;


//Data for section 2
@property(nonatomic,copy) NSString * section2a;
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger section2b;

+ (id)sharedInstance;
@end
```

MyManager.m

```
@implementation MyManager
@synthesize section1a, section1b, section2a; , section2b;

+ (id)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    __strong static id _sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        _sharedObject = [[self alloc] init]; // or some other init method
    });
    return _sharedObject;
}
@end
```

So I use it as follows:

```
MyManager * myManager = [MyManager sharedInstance];
myManager.data = self.data
```

Is this how you generally use the singleton? Am I missing anything? 
Sorry for the basic questions I just want to make sure I am doing it right.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure which differences do you mean in iOS 5 or other version. But I think you missing declare this in .m file: static MyManager *_sharedObject = nil;

Comment: just for your sake, you would implement these two methods in your singleton class (besides the `+sharedInstance` method) `+allocWithZone:` and `+copyWithZone:`, and you can add a `static MyManager *_sharedObject;` member for your class as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right. This is (currently :) the way to go and works fine with ARC enabled, multiple threads etc.

It isn't strictly a singleton, as you can alloc more instances of the class, but I don't think that's relevant in your case.

Comment: can you help edit my code a bit so that it acts like a true singleton?

Comment: I would actually advise against it, as there is almost never a reason to do so. The code you've posted works fine as it is. A "real" singleton would mean fiddling around with manual memory management - something that I'm glad I rarely have to do these days. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a singleton because you can create multiple instances of this class with alloc/init methods.
A right answer [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470112/how-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-my-iphone-project/11470197#11470197)

Comment: Well, this works, but a determined person will use the runtime methods like `class_createInstance`

Answer (score 0):

I usually make my singleton as such (suppose we are making a singleton for Manager):

```
static (Manager *) instance;

+ (Manager *) getInstance
{
    if(!instance) instance = [[Manager alloc] init];
    return instance;
}
```

This is a very basic singleton (it doesn't take into account multithreading or other advanced features) but this is the basic format.

Comment: Bad idea, multithreaded code will make this fail faster than pulling the plug on your desktop.

Comment: I agree that multithreading code will make this fail; however, he never states that he wants a thread-safe singleton.  I was just showing him the bare bones version

Comment: @Nosrettap the whole point of a singleton is one instance. If multiple instances can be allocated, then this is not a singleton!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII If the program does not access this with multiple threads, then there will only be one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this: [Singleton in iOS 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796529/singleton-in-ios-5/11564881#11564881) You should override allowWithZone to prevent rogue code from creating a new instance.